# max value for SO_RCVBUF in Windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, networking, sockets

Quick question, wondering if anyone knew what the limit is for SO_RCVBUF under Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO_RCVBUF in winsock is not limited by the TCP window size. At least for pre-Vista stacks. It would be limited by non-paged pool availability, which is a whole different topic.
So you can make it quite big, if you want to.

Obligatory unsolicited advice: If you are using a large buffer because you are receiving infrequently, I would look into asynchronous I/O with events/select/completion ports.

Answer (score 2):

I can't recall for sure, but I believe Windows supports the POSIX function `fpathconf()` with the `_PC_SOCK_MAXBUF` option. If so, this is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/wndp/archive/2006/05/05/Winhec-blog-tcpip-2.aspx), it looks like the maximum is 64K.

Comment: I am not sure this is correct.  I'm setting it to values significantly larger without error.  The article you quote is rather old.

Answer (score 0):

Based on MsQuic source code
max SO_RCVBUF is INT32_MAX